# Launch native apps from custom cordova app

Tags: android, cordova, mobile-development

I'm developing a mobile app with Cordova (in Intel XDK) which is a list of buttons that launches other apps.

So far I've managed to launch phone app (`href="tel://"`), sms (`href="sms://`) and google website in browser (`href="http://google.com"`).

I've found a plugin for starting apps: https://github.com/lampaa/com.lampa.startapp but basing on guide provided there I can launch an app with code like this (example) :

```
navigator.startApp.start([["app.com.name", "app.com.name.Activity"], [{"product_id":"100"}]], ...);
```

But how can I find those full app names (these `app.com.name` strings) ?

I need names for these apps (or way how to open them):

- Videos (default app for android),
- Pictures / Camera Roll (default app for android),
- Camera,
- WiFi settings,
- Bluetooth settings,
- Browser window with **blank** or home page opened.

Just to remind: I don't want to sync any data between these apps and mine - I just want simply to launch it via my app.

If You have other solutions - I'm open for any suggestions.

Comment: if you want to handle documents using available apps on phone then plugin is available for that : https://github.com/ti8m/DocumentHandler i am using this for handle docs and pics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Videos (default app for android),

Requires [InAppBrowser](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser) Plugin to be installed. In your code simply call `cordova.InAppBrowser.open('videos://', '_system', 'location=yes');`

### Pictures / Camera Roll (default app for android) & Camera

Requires [Camera](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera) Plugin.
`navigator.camera.getPicture(cameraSuccess, cameraError, cameraOptions);`

### Settings

Check out this [Native Settings](https://github.com/selahssea/Cordova-open-native-settings) Plugin

### Browser window with blank or home page opened.

Requires [InAppBrowser](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser) Plugin to be installed. In your code simply call `cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://google.org', '_system', 'location=yes');` This will open the default browser installed.

Many apps have well known URL Schemes defined that you can use to open app directly with. Heres a [list](http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes). Whichever app URL you're using, make sure you add it to your whitelist in `config.xml`. 
`<allow-intent href="twitter:*" />`
`<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />` 
The more recent approach is to use Universal Links as apposed to the URL.

Comment: thanks for useful answer, only `videos://` doesn't work - after click nothing happens (I've installed `InAppBrowser` btw)