# Can we use in-app integration inside our cordova/phonegap hybrid application ,

Tags: cordova, native, phonegap, hybrid, in-app

just like the one in the native application of yatra in which it is embedding uber
can we open an android native app from our hybrid application without creating a separate icon inside our phone

Comment: yes why not the are so many plugin avl for in-app in cordova or phonegap

Comment: Thanks for your reply
it would be great if you could provide with the name of any plugin @gauravsingh

Comment: try using `https://github.com/lampaa/com.lampa.startapp ` and `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36362096/launch-native-apps-from-custom-cordova-app`

Comment: @gaurav singh I have used this plugin , but this plugin is used to open an app if it is already installed or iredirect it to the playstore but in my case i am talking about the scenarion of uber inside the yatra app , the do not redirect to the uber app but they open it inside their app itself. It is called as in-app integration 
So my question here is that can i put an apk inside my hybrid app so that i can use that when i install my hybrid app side by side